# NSNotificationCenter Thread breaks at second call even after it has been removed

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, nsnotificationcenter

I am using `NSNotificationCenter` for two different ViewControllers. First time calling `NSNotificationCenter` works well and after that I remove the observer. But if I run it again, the thread breaks even after removing the observer.

in ViewController1:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"textUpdateNotification" object: nil ];
```

in ViewController2:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receiveNotification:) name:@"textUpdateNotification" object:nil];

-(void)receiveNotification:(NSNotification *)notificaton
{
....
....
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"textUpdateNotification" object:nil];
}
```

I tried with removing the observer in `- (void)dealloc` there also the same thing is happening.
[image]

Comment: Post the stacktrace.

Comment: notificationcenter doesnt work in que, we need to remove the observer

Comment: That stacktrace appears to have nothing to do with your question...

Comment: actually am getting the thread bad access. its not showing anything in console

Comment: What is a "thread bad access"? The crash happens in `PickerDismissal:` (`SOLS_AS_CreateAccountDetailViewController `). (And you should really use the Objective-C naming conventions.)

Comment: Dude you have already removed your notification observer. 
Thats why it displaying this error. Comment the removeobserver method and try to do same thing..

Comment: Last thing. If your second controller has finished then how it will get the notification. 
You are writing very bad coding in your program without any flow.

Comment: after calling the nsnotification center only am removing the observer not before.@V.J.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for my typo,
I am removing observer in the source ViewController where I am triggering the NSNotification, I should remove it from second ViewController where its being used.

in ViewController1:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"textUpdateNotification" object: nil ];
```

in ViewController2:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receiveNotification:) name:@"textUpdateNotification" object:nil];

    -(void)receiveNotification:(NSNotification *)notificaton
    {
    ....
    ....
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"textUpdateNotification" object:nil];
    }

- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"textUpdateNotification" object:nil];
}
```

Thanks for every one

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the observer in `viewDidDisappear`

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"textUpdateNotification" object:nil];
}
```